# What are the recommended approaches for automating the certificate update process in mobile apps?

Tags: react-native, security, firewall

My mobile app is required to carry a certificate to call APIs through a firewall, which enhances the security of our system.

here is detail article about building secure native apps with self-signed SSL certificates using Certificate Pinning
https://www.browserstack.com/blog/building-secure-native-apps-with-self-signed-ssl-certificates-using-certificate-pinning/

To ensure continuous security, we have to follows a key rotation routine that requires me to renew the certificate every year.

However, the current process involves manually updating the source code of the app, changing the certificate, and uploading the updated version to the relevant app stores.

Additionally, we need to enforce app upgrades to ensure compatibility with the new certificate, as our backend system follows a Big Band Approach for certificate changes.

Failure to update the app will result in API call failures when interacting with the firewall.

I want to seek advice on how to handle this certificate rotation process more efficiently.

What are the recommended approaches for automating the certificate update process in mobile apps?